# Как задать ограничения на параметры шаблонных классов?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть абстрактный класс `M` и классы `A`, `B` и `C`, для которых `М` - родительский класс, и в них реализованы все абстрактные методы класса `М`.
Нужно создать шаблонный класс

```
template <class T> class S{ ... };
```

в котором качестве шаблона используются классы `A`, `B` или `C`.
Можно как-то указать, что `M` должен быть родительским классом для `Т`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вас спасет `std::is_base_of`:

```
struct M {};

struct A: public M {};

struct B {};

template<class T, typename=std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<M,T>::value>>
struct S {};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    S<A> a;
    S<B> b;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Один из способов - это просто объявить, например, `typedef` для базового класса шаблонного параметра внутри шаблонного класса. Если шаблонный параметр не имеет такого базового класса, то будет выдано сообщение об ошибке.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>

class M
{
    virtual void f() const = 0;
};

class A : public M
{
    virtual void f() const
    {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
};

template <class T>
class S
{
    typedef typename T::M Base;
};

int main() 
{
    S<A> s1;
//  S<B> s2;

    return 0;
}
```

Если раскомментировать в этой программе закомментированное предложение, то компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 3):

А если у вас старый компилятор, то можно пойти длинным путем:

```
class M
{
    virtual void f() const = 0;
};

class A : public M
{
    virtual void f() const
    {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
};

template<typename D, typename B>
class IsDerivedFrom
{
    class No {};
    class Yes { No no[2]; };
    static Yes Test(B*);
    static No  Test(...);
public:
    enum { Is = sizeof(Test(static_cast<D*>(0))) == sizeof(Yes) };
};

template <class T, int = IsDerivedFrom<T,M>::Is>
class S
{
};

template <class T>
class S<T,0>
{   S() { char * p = (int*)0; }
};


int main() 
{
    S<A> s1;
    S<B> s2;

    return 0;
}
```

Зато работает на старых компиляторах, которые не знают C++ 11.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class M {
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class A: public M {
public:
    virtual void f() { std::cout << "class a\n"; }
};

class B {
public:
    virtual void f() { std::cout << "class b\n"; }
};

template<class T, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<M, T>::value>::type>
class S
{
public:
    T t;
    void f() { this->t.f(); }
};

int main() {
    S<A> a;
    //S<B> b;
    return 0;
}
```

Если раскомментировать `S<B> b`, то выдастся ошибка при компиляции.